# jquery validation always fails

Tags: jquery-plugins

Why is the following validation function always failing. It even fails if I have both return case with true.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validate_old_password", function(value, element){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users/ajaxPage_password_validation/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        debug: true,
        data: {
            password: $("#id_old_password").val()
        },
        success: function(response){
            if (response == "True") {
                console.log('aa')
                return true;
            }// correct PW
            return false; // bad PW
        }
    })
}, "password not valid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because of the deferred execution.

**When the "validate_old_password" method is called it simply kicks off the ajax call and continues to the end of the method, it won't wait around for the response.**

You may want to consider using the [remote validation options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) in the validation plugin.